# prove that the derivative has at least $m - r$ zeroes

Tags: calculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Let $P$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients. Suppose the distinct zeroes (possibly complex) of $P$ are $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_r\}$ and let the distinct zeroes of $P+1$ be $\{\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_s\}$. Prove (or disprove) that, counting multiplicities, $P'$ has at least $m-r$ zeroes in $\{\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_r\}$ and at least $m-s$ in $\{\mu_1,\cdots, \mu_s\}$.

I know that if $P$ has a zero of multiplicity $a$, then $P'$ has the same zero of multiplicity $a-1$. Also, linear terms of polynomials are irreducible in the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ (and maybe over most, if not all, fields too). Also, clearly the zeroes of $P$ and $P+1$ are disjoint. If the zeroes of $P$ were all real and distinct, Rolle's theorem could be applied to get at least $m-r = 0$ zeroes in $\{\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_r\}$ and similarly if the zeroes of $P+1$ were all distinct and real.

How can I make progress on this problem?  I'm quite sure it's true.

Comment: I assume that $m$ is the degree of the polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_r$ be the multiplicities of the distinct zeros $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_r$ of $P$. Then
$$
 k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_r = m
$$
where $m$ is the degree of $P$, and therefore
$$
 (k_1 - 1) + (k_2-1) + \cdots + (k_r - 1) = m-r \, .
$$
The left-hand side is the total number of zeros of $P'$ in $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots, \lambda_r\} $, counting multiplicities.

The same argument works with the zeros of $P+1$.